# Секунды:миллисекунды перевести в минуты:секунды в таймере

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть таймер на 3 минуты.

```
timeStart = 180f;
```

В обычном виде он выводится секунды:миллисекунды (180:00 и идёт в уменьшение до 0).
Я бы хотел это время перевести в минуты:секунды (3:00, 2:59, 2:58...).
Делаю это так:

```
Timer.text = (timeStart / 60).ToString("F0") + ":" + (timeStart % 60).ToString("F0");
```

Но выходит криво, начинается не с 3:00,2:59..., а 3:60,3:59... А также при 3:30 число изменяется на 2:30. Что не так делаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Изучите класс TimeSpan, он всё умеет, что вам нужно.

Comment: Не может код `timeStart % 60` выдать число `60`, вы чего-то либо недоговариваете, либо рассказываете не про этот код, а про какой-то другой. Единственное, что еще могу предположить, что timeStart - не целое число. Должно быть `int`, измените тип переменной. `ToString("F0")` можно убрать, целые числа всегда отображаются как целые. Но решение через TimeSpan - все равно более грамотное.

Comment: ничего не нужно изучать. можно все исправить за 1 секунду. сделайте timeStart целым и тогда математические операции будут работать, как вы планировали.

Comment: Спасибо вам обоим! Да, действительно, нужно было просто timeStart сделать не float, а int.

Comment: `TimeSpan` попробуйте, он из коробки умеет отображаться как время. Например `new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180).ToString("mm:ss")`, вроде так. Либо `.ToString("mm\\:ss")`, точно не припомню.